# Bio.Phylo.PAML.codeml's results parser quietly fails to read all the data

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence

**Biopython** comes with methods to interface with the **PAML** package for phylogenetic analysis.

In particular I am using [**Bio.Phylo.PAML**](http://biopython.org/wiki/PAML) to run analyses using PAML's codeml.exe program which in my case does Ka/Ks (dN/dS) ratio analysis on pairs of orthologous gene sequences.

After running the analysis using `results = cml.run()` I can see it has successfully generated `result.out` files that look about right. Most importantly the final line of the file is what I need to parse into Python:

```
t= 0.2173  S=   703.9  N=  1489.1  dN/dS=  0.2247  dN = 0.0344  dS = 0.1529
```

What I am most interested in is `dN/dS = 0.2247`

According to Biopython's [**PAML wiki**](http://biopython.org/wiki/PAML) this value can be obtained from Python by doing `results = cml.run()` which generates a dictionary with a set of values I am interested in after running the analysis. The wiki claims I can find the values I need in a key called `'parameters'`. But this only returns one of the values I need `t= 0.2173`, look:

```
>>> results.values()
['Fcodon', 'One dN/dS ratio for branches, ', '4.7b', {0: {'description': 'one-ratio', 'parameters': {'t': 0.1982}}}, {'htlv': {}, 'stlv': {}}]
```

Notice, that my parameters key only contains the `t= 0.2173` and has omitted `S=   703.9  N=  1489.1  dN/dS=  0.2247  dN = 0.0344  dS = 0.1529`

Could anybody with `codeml` experience explain to me why the parser fails to yield most of the parameters (values) I am interested in?

**Extra details**

- Using Python2.7, PAML4.7a
- Running on Windows 7
- I will readily edit in any data or info you require to help me fix this

Comment: Been hacking away at this problem for a while now, what is quite mysterious is that the PAML manual is given as version 4.7a (2013 May) whilst the codeml program I am using states it is PAML 4.7b (2013 Sep)... hmm perhaps this could be a very new bug caused by Biopython not yet being updated to deal with the new codeml version?

Comment: Probably if you ask it in the biopython mailing list you will get more answers. I don't know anything about the Bio.Phylo.PAML ...

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm interested in the same problem.

Comment: @biojl not that I've checked, I've imported an answer from biostars, let me know if that helps, otherwise I'll export it to ResearchGate

Answer (score 3):

Cross-posting from https://www.biostars.org/p/89848/:

You can obtain omega values for each branch using the following commands:

```
from Bio.Phylo.PAML import codeml

results = codeml.read(paml_outputfile)

print results["NSsites"][0]["parameters"]["omega"]
```

This gives you a list of omega (dn/ds) for each branch

using version 4.7b and biopython-1.6.3

Comment: @biojl I've reported this as a possible bug on the official github: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/483